# Unexpected character when writting to Excel using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a `dictionary` like this:

```
film = {
    'ID': [],
    'Name': [],
    'Run Time': [],
    'Genre': [],
    'link': [],
    'name 2': []
}
```

Then I populate it in a for loop, like this:

```
film['ID'].append(film_id)
film['Name'].append(film_name)
film['Run Time'].append(film_runtime)
film['Genre'].append(film_genre)
film['link'].append(film_link)
film['name 2'].append(film_name2)
```

Then I convert the dictionary to a Pandas DataFrame, so that I can write it to an `.xlsx` file. Now before I actually write it, I print it to check the values of `Run Time` column. And everything is OK:

```
output_df = pd.DataFrame(film).set_index('ID')
print(output_df['Run Time'])

output:
ID
102    131
103     60
104       
105       
Name: Run Time, dtype: object
```

But then, when I write it, like this:

```
writer = ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
output_df.to_excel(writer, 'فیلم')
writer.save()
```

The file looks like this:

[image: weird output]

As you can see, there's an extra `'` (single quote) character in the file. This character is not visible. But I can highlight it:

[image: highlighted]

And if I remove it, the number goes `RTL`:

[image: removed]

So I thought the invisible character was [LTR MARK](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm) (`\u200E`). I removed it like this:

```
film['Run Time'].append(film_runtime.replace('\u200E', ''))
```

But nothing happened, and the character is still there.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Not sure, can you try using `'RunTime': [],` instead of `'Run Time': [],` and then change `film['Run Time'].append(film_runtime)` to `film['RunTime'].append(film_runtime)`.

Comment: @AviThour I changed both of `Run Time`s to `RunTime`, but the character is still there.

Comment: Is the ‘film_runtime’ variable a string or a number?

Comment: @quamrana It was the result of a regex match `runtime_match.group(1)`. I converted it to `int` and the problem is solved! Thank you. Can you form an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that cells that need to be numbers are converted to numbers (typically ints) before converting to an .xlsx file.

In your case just:

```
film['Run Time'].append(int(film_runtime))
```

Answer (score 0):

The ' before a value in Excel forces the value to string. Looks like the Excel Writer is interpreting such list as an string array. 
Changing the type in the DataFrame should solve it.